# Two Columns of data in the same Column. How do I format this table correctly?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, format, html-table

My output right now is stacking one column on top of the other. How can I get the second column next to the first column, instead of below it?

edit1: added HTML output.
edit2: okay to elaborate, the do loop is operating on a hash of data.
{ site1 => 1, site2 =>1, site3 =>4} it's something like that.

I want an output of:

sites :: data 
site1 :: 3
site2 :: 2
site3 :: 5

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>>7days</th>
  <th><7days</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <% @ls7days.values.each do |ls7day| %>

  <td><%= ls7day %></td>
</tr>
  <%end%>

<tr>
  <% @gt7days.values.each do |gt7day| %>

  <td><%= gt7day %></td>
</tr>
  <%end%>      

</table>
```

HTML output

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>>7days</th>
<th>>7days</th
</tr>

  <td>53</td>
</tr>

  <td>13</td>
</tr>

  <td>49</td>
</tr>

  <td>8</td>
</tr>

  <td>64</td>
</tr>    

</table>
```

Comment: well it's not too clear what you're asking... but I'm going to guess it is related to your columns being named with a literal > in them... also your <tr> need to fall inside the each like the </tr>... or else your </tr> needs to fall outside the each like the <tr> also your second th is missing a > on the </th>...  lastly, I don't think you're building that table like you think you are... can you give an example of the generated html you are expecting?

Comment: i updated with the html output and fixed a few typos.

basically i just need to know if there is something like <tc></tc> which would place it in a column instead of a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, well it seems like you still have some formatting mistakes in your original code, so let's start by correcting those.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>&gt;7days</th>
    <th>&lt;7days</th>
  </tr>

  <% @ls7days.values.each do |ls7day| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= ls7day %></td>
    </tr>
  <%end%>


  <% @gt7days.values.each do |gt7day| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= gt7day %></td>
    </tr>
  <%end%>      

</table>
```

Note that I replaced the > and < in the ths with `&gt;` and `&lt;` as well as moved the opens for your trs inside the each.

Now that we have fixed the formatting errors we have some issues with the actual structure of the table.  I think this step calls for some explanation as to what the different components of a table are for.

- First, you have the `<table></table>` tags, these are pretty
  straight-forward as they signal a table.
- Next, you have the `<tr></tr>` tags, these represent the rows of the
  table. These tags are known as Table Row tags.
- Lastly, you have the `<td></td>` tags, these represent the cells of the
  table. These tags are known as Table Data tags, and are probably the
  most confusing part of a table.  They represent the individual data
  cells and as such in a way represent your columns.  All table rows in
  a table should have the same number of table datas.
- Technically, there are some additional tags such as the `<th></th>`
  tags, but these can effectively be thought of as `<td><h3></h3></td>`. 
  They are hardly different from a table data.

Looking back at your table's structure we see that the first table row has two table datas in it.  Then every table row after that has only a single td in it.  As such, the behavior of your table is unstable and may display differently from one browser to another.  In order to fix this you simply need to add another table data to each table row.

My guess, given your comments, is that you actually were trying to use the each statements to generate the columns of your table.  Because of the way that a table is structured this is not as simple as it might seem, but let's give it a shot.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><h4>&gt;7days</h4></td>
    <td><h4>&lt;7days</h4></td>
  </tr>


  <% if @ls7days.values.size > @gt7days.values.size %>
    <% @ls7days.values.each_with_index do |ls7day, index| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= @gt7days.values[index] unless index >= @gt7days.size %></td>
        <td><%= ls7day %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <% @gt7days.values.each_with_index do |gt7day, index| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= gt7day %></td>
        <td><%= @ls7days.values[index] unless index >= @ls7days.size %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

</table>
```

As you can see, we now iterate over the larger of the two arrays (gt7days and lt7days).  As we do we put its value into a table data in a new table row as you were originally doing.  However, we also put the value from the smaller array into another table data in that same table row.  Which should work great, except it is probably possible (maybe even likely) that the two arrays are not the same size.  So, we handle that by saying that we are going to grab the value from the smaller array unless the value we want won't exist (we know it won't because its place in the array is past the arrays size).

It may not be the most elegant solution, but I think it will work how you are expecting.

Comment: thank you for your post. it was very informative.

i have another question. say i had several more columns i wanted to add. gt30days gt90days gt180days and gt365days.

how would i got about adding them in?

Comment: glad I could help... as far as adding in additional columns, you can do it in the same way that this is set up just make sure that you are using the array with the most values for the each_with_index... if I were you though, I would look at structuring the data differently, perhaps as an array of hashes? each hash could have a key per column... generating the array of hashes structure would then allow you to do something like <% hsh_arr.each do |item| %><tr><td><%= item[lt7days] %></td><td><%= item[gt7days] %></td></tr><% end %> of course you can then add additional tds for whatever has a key

Answer (score 0):

Your th tag might be wrong.

It should be like this:

```
<th>7days</th>
<th>7days</th>
```

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

- Extra > removed on th's
- added > on last /th>
- added  on 2nd and 3rd rows.

I think you're after this... and are we missing the < td > for first column on 2nd and 3rd rows?

```
 <table>
<tr>
  <th>7days</th>
  <th>7days</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <% @ls7days.values.each do |ls7day| %>

  <td><%= ls7day %></td>
</tr>
  <%end%>

<tr>
  <% @gt7days.values.each do |gt7day| %>

  <td><%= gt7day %></td>
</tr>
  <%end%>      

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put them in separate table rows.  Use separate columns.

Each  tag is a separate row below the next.  Each  tag is a separate column next to the previous.  If you want values next to each other, put them in adjacent  tags.

Comment: how do you put them in separate columns?